# Import CSV files from BLOB to Database Table

Tags: sql, csv, blob

I have a table in MS SQL Express that is storing csv files as blobs. I want to import those csv files into a table. The columns in the csv match the columns in the database table. Is this possible? Here is my simplified example:

CSV blob store table:

```
Table CSVStore
(ReportID, File image, FileName nvarchar (200))
```

My CSV file has columns

```
(FirstName, LastName, DOB)
```

My SQL Table

```
Table Employees

(EmployeeID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
FirstName nvarchar (100),
LastName nvarchar (100),
DOB datetime,
Primary Key (EmployeeID))
```

How do I get the CSV data from CSVStore when ReportID = 1 into my table Employees?

Comment: You can do it programatically with an external program that retrieves the files from the blobs and examines them. What are your exact requirements?

Comment: I just wanted to find out if there was a simple SQL query / script that could import the blob file into a table. I just can't see an example anywhere.

Comment: is there anyway in the CSV file mentioned the database table name ? There are columns but how do you know which table you want to insert ?

Comment: Both tables are in the same database.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can using `OpenRowSet` Command to work with that.

```
INSERT INTO db.CSV
(
  FileName,
  FileContent
)
SELECT 'file1.csv', BlobFile.*
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\CSV\file1.csv', single_blob) BlobFile
```

There is an arctile [Working with Large Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t%28VS.80%29.aspx) which you may find it useful.

Comment: Thanks - I am being a little obtuse on this so I bit more help would be appreciated. I have a table for the CSV files called Reportstore with the columns FileName nvarchar (100) and CSV File image. The CSV files have for instance 2 columns Firstname and Lastname. The table that I want to import this into say Employeedetails has 2 columns Firstname and Lastname. How would the SQL script for this look?

Comment: Can you put the CSV files example in the question? seem like you need to write a custom bulk insert manipulation in SQL.